# Automatic scene detection

Tags: linux, video-editing

I'm looking for a program which is able to split movie into parts depending on a scene change. So if movie consists of forest landscape and fishes in aquarium  then I want to get two movies: the first is about the forest, the second is about fishes. Preferably the program is available under Linux and has command line interface

Answer (score 6):

All I could find so far:

- The program `lav2yuv` can detect scene changes:

  ```
  -S list.el
  Output a scene list with scene detection
  ```

  For this to work, you'd need to convert your video files to MJPEG before:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i source.avi -an -vcodec mjpeg destination.avi
  ```

---

- There's an abandoned piece of software called [shotdetect](http://shotdetect.nonutc.fr/). It's the only command-line and open source program I ever found, but I expect it not to work for most videos.

Comment: Do you know anything about the contents inside that file? What do the numbers represent? My guess is those are frame numbers - any clue if that's right?

Comment: The `list.el` file? I have no idea since I've never tried it, but I would guess these are frames, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Scenalyzer Live](http://scenalyzer.com/) with great success. It does scene detection, but it is a Windows GUI tool, not Linux command-line:

> ScLive has automatic scene splitting while capturing - each scene is written into its own .avi file in realtime.
>   It splits the scenes based on the recording-time embedded in the DV-streams or based on optical content.

Answer (score 3):

According to its webpage (http://www.kdenlive.org/users/j-b-m/preparing-new-kdenlive-release ), Kdenlive have this functionality ( called Clip analysis feature ).

Answer (score 3):

I found this post a few days ago looking for a solution to auto split clips. I ended up making a bash script. Hope this helps someone, Since my google search brought me here in the first place and i was already member to the stack exchange i decided to post it here hoping it will help someone else.

I don't know if i have the right to put a disclaimer but you will be advise that it is given as is without guarantee and if you (or it) mess something, i'm not resposible. It's one of my first script and i have very little experience in bash so if a guru of bash want to tweak this even more, please be my guess.Feel free to modify, share and use the script.

## Usage: sh ./scenesplit.sh inputfile.mp4

- The script will create a folder named after the input file in the
  current path and output the cutted scenes in it
- It will create a file with the showinfo from ffmpeg
- From this file it will output another file with the timestamp of each detection
- The script will then loop ffmpeg to create a series of clip according to
  the timestamp file. The first clip start at 0 and end at the first
  timestamp. The last clip start at the last timestamp and ends a the
  end of the original clip.
- Will sleep a second bewteen each scene.

You can adjust the 'sensitivity' of the detection by changing the value of `gt(scene,0.1)`. Needs to be a value bewteen 0 and 1. They recommend (is sane as they say) bewteen 0.4 and 0.6 but 0.1 works fine for me.

The output codec is set to mp4 with aac audio at 30fps 720p.

Work as intended (for me) with mp4 files. Didn't test with any other codec.

```
#/bin/bash

start=0; 
count=0; 
in="$1"
bn="$(basename "$in")"
echo "=============================================================================="
echo "FILE START: $bn"
mkdir "./$bn"

echo "Finding Scene... this might take a while..."
ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$in" -filter:v "select='gt(scene,0.1)',showinfo" -f null - 2>"./$bn/ffout.tmp.txt"

echo "Filtering timestamp... this might take a while..."
grep showinfo "./$bn/ffout.tmp.txt" | grep pts_time:[0-9.]* -o | grep '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' -o > "./$bn/timestamps.tmp.txt"

scenes=$(wc -l < "./$bn/timestamps.tmp.txt")
echo "Found $scenes scenes"
sleep 1

while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    echo "SCENE START: $count/$scenes ($start,$line)"
    ffmpeg -i "$in" -ss "$start" -to "$line" -nostdin -y -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -g 120 -s 1280x720 -r 30 "./$bn/$bn.($count of $scenes).mp4"
    echo "SCENE DONE:$count/$scenes ($start,$line)"
    echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    start=$line
    count=$(($count+1))
    sleep 1

done <"./$bn/timestamps.tmp.txt"
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "LAST SCENE START:$count/$scenes ($start,end)"
ffmpeg -i "$in" -ss "$start" -nostdin -y -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -g 120 -s 1280x720 -r 30 "./$bn/$bn.($count of $scenes).mp4"
echo "LAST SCENE DONE:$count/$scenes ($start,end)"
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"

echo "FILE DONE: $bn"
echo "=============================================================================="
```

Hope this helps,
llt

Comment: Great script! Instead of `bn="$(basename "$in")"` I removed extension with
`bn=${in%.*}`